# simulring and collect digits from dialed number to accept call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twimlet

We've got a basic twiml set up that sends a call to multiple destinations, it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+1800XXXXXXX</Number>
        <Number>+1912XXXXXXX</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem is I want to have one of the destination parties press a digit ( like "1" for example ) before twilio actually bridges the call to them.

I've looked at  but that only seems to get digits from the caller, not the callee.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To have the recipient of a call started by a `<Number>` perform an action, you need to provide a URL as the [`url` attribute of the `<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url). When the call connects, Twilio will make a webhook request to that URL and you can return TwiML from the URL. Within that TwiML you can include a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) to have the recipient enter a digit before you connect the call. See the documentation for the [`url` attribute for `<Number>` for more detail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url).